# SQL Server 2008 R2 + Create new instance

Tags: sql-server, sql, service-pack

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 that's running as default instance. This instance has been patched with SP1 earlier this year.

I would like to create a new instance for a new application. Once the installation for the new instance is completed, do I need to re-run the service pack installer again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Service pack installs (and ultimately MSSQL Server versions) are per-instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should but maybe [this](http://www.sqlserverclub.com/articles/how-to-upgrade-sql-server-instances-quickly-and-quietly.aspx) wil help? Btw I'm always curious why anybody wants to use multiple instances because from a maintenance point of view its fare from ideal. Good luck!

Comment: People do it for a few reasons. One being security isolation. For example, if you have a MS SQL server on the trusted side of your firewall, and you want to have internal apps use it as well as apps in your DMZ, it's not uncommon to have one instance for the DMZ apps and another for the internal apps. That way, if an instance is compromised because of a password leak or whatever, only the DBs in that instance are impacted.

Comment: we have a workgroup edition, which has a 4GB memory limit per instance if I understand the feature table published by MS well.

our existing instance is using up about 3.7GB of memory. Our server has 12GB of memory so I thought setting up a new instance would allow the sql server to better utilize the system memory.

Comment: Ah ok, if you really want to separate security in that strict way then I can imagine this to be a good reason.

Comment: @gostan I forgot about some of those strange limits they have for SQL. Yes in this situation this can work ofc because SQL can now allocate twice as much memory. Another valid reason for me.